# Expressing polynomials as binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

Is there a way to check whether or not a certain polynomial function (of any degree) can be expressed as a binomial coefficient?

That is to say, we have the polynomial

$f(x)=n_0x^3+n_1x^2+n_3x+n_4$,

how do we know if it is possible to express $f(x)$ as$\binom{ax+b}{cx+d}$?

Additionally, if possible, how would one go about deriving the binomial expression algebraically? This is essentially working backwards from the expansion of a binomial coefficient.

Comment: As a side note, your question would be better received if you showed what you have tried. This enables us to find out where you got stuck and prevents closure/deletion of the question. For example, have you considered looking at polynomials of the form $(x+a)^n$?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire is that really necessary for this problem? It's not an exercise

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin Of course, I never said that it was a necessity. It would be more insightful if OP included their thought process.

Comment: One or two examples would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the expression $\binom{ax+b}{cx+d}$ is never a polynomial when $c\neq 0$. This follows since $\binom{ax+b}{cx+d}\ge \big(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}\big)^{cx+d}$, and the latter grows exponentially as $x\to\infty$ if $c\neq 0$.

Therefore, you can restrict your attention to expressions like $\binom{ax+b}{k}$. When you expand this out in powers of $x$, the highest degree term is $\frac{a^k}{k!}x^k$, and the constant term is $\binom{b}k$. Therefore, you can determine $a,b$ and $k$ by looking at the leading and constant terms of $f(x)$, plug those into $\binom{ax+b}k$, then see if the result is equal to $f(x)$. If it is, you are done, if not, then $f$ cannot be written in this form.